# BottomBar android library

Tags: android

I'm using BottomBar android library but I can't find any method to set this position in bottom I use mBottomBar.setDefaultTabPosition(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM); but it's not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a glance reading from [BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) library, there it said:

> Can I use it by XML?
>
> No, but you can still put it anywhere in the View hierarchy. Just attach it to >any View you want like this:
>
> mBottomBar.attach(findViewById(R.id.myContent), savedInstanceState);

And from the sample code, it looks like you should only attach it to your view.

I'll stand corrected.

Comment: Please add your xml file in your question.

Comment: Ok I see the Customization sorry